# Return the index of selected item in Matlab pop-up menu

Tags: matlab, user-interface, popup, indices

I would like to get the index of selected item in a pop-up menu in the Matlab GUI. For that I wrote this under pop-up callback function:

```
contents = cellstr(get(h0bject,'String'));
theItem = contents{get(h0bject,'Value')};
theindex = find(contents == theItem);
```

Matlab returns:

```
Undefined function 'eq' for input arguments of type 'cell'
```

Then I wrote

```
contents = cellstr(get(h0bject,'String'));
theItem = contents{get(h0bject,'Value')};
contents = cell2mat(contents):
theItem = str2num(theItem);
theindex = find(contents == theItem);
```

Matlab returns

```
index = Empty matrix: 0-by-1
```

For sure `theItem` is in the `contents`. How can I get the index? Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Value` of a pop-up menu is set to the *index* of the selected item. So if you've selected the second of three items, the `Value` will be 2, and you can fetch it using `selectedIdx = get(hObject, 'Value')`.

The `String` of a pop-pup menu can be set to *either* a cell array of strings, one per item; or a character array, with one row per item.

If you've set the `String` to be a cell array of strings, you can get the selected item using `items = get(hObject, 'String'); selectedItem = items{selectedIdx}`.

If you've set the `String` to be a character array, you can get the selected item using `items = get(hObject, 'String'); selectedItem = items(selectedIdx, :)`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes, later I found the solution as you explained. Anyway, thank you very much.